# If $i_1 : k \rightarrow K$ and $i_2 : K \rightarrow k$ are fields extension, do we have $k \cong K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

The question is quite simple, but yet I don't succeed to prove or disprove it.

> If $i_1 : k \rightarrow K$ and $i_2 : K
> \rightarrow k$ are fields extension, do we have $k \cong K$ ?

Someone could help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend $k:=\mathbb C$ to $K:=\mathbb C(X)$ and then to its algebraic completion $\cong k$.

$k \not\cong K$ since every element of $k$ has a square root.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !

Answer (score 3):

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be elliptic curves over $\Bbb Q$ which are isogenous, but not isomorphic. Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be their function fields. There are then isogenies
$i_1:E_1\to E_2$ and $i_2:E_2\to E_1$. These induce maps of function fields
$i_1^*:K_2\to K_1$ and $i_2^*:K_1\to K_2$. Then $K_2$ is isomorphic to a finite
extension of $K_1$, and *vice versa* yet $K_1$ and $K_2$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: Yeah, this was the example I would have used. You don’t need the base to be $\Bbb Q$, do you?